# Get table row object inside javascript function - DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtmlx

We are doing cross browser compatibility for an application which was built over 8 years ago. The app works only in IE. Now we are making it work in Chrome too. The application had used 1.5 version of DHTMLX. Now we have replaced it to version 3.5. After upgradation to 3.5, we are having some issues. At some places, we are getting NULL values in Chrome when debugged in the console. 
For example, we have this below function. On click of a DHTMLX grid checkbox, this function is called.

```
var glbGroupId=null;
function setRowCellVals(){

    if(arguments[0]!=null){
        radioFlag = true;
        src=$(arguments[0]);
        if(!glbCheckAction){
            if(src.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].checked){
                src.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].checked=false;
            }else{
                src.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].checked=true;
            }
        }
        glbCheckAction = false;
        glbGroupId=src.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value;

        document.manageKpiGroupForm.parent_GId.value = src.id;
        document.manageKpiGroupForm.parent_Gname.value = src.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        document.manageKpiGroupForm.parent_mId.value = $F('moduleCmb');
        document.manageKpiGroupForm.parent_mName.value = src.childNodes[3].innerHTML;
        document.manageKpiGroupForm.parent_gDesc.value = src.childNodes[4].innerHTML;
        moduleRowId=arguments[0];
        return true;
    }
}
```

In Chrome, the `src` is being rendered as NULL. We checked the same function in IE, in another copy which has the older version of DHTMLX, the `src` value comes as [object DispHTMLTableRow] in the IE console. Any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the reason of the issue cannot be found with the provided code.
Please provide with a more detailed sample or with the link to the demo, where the problem can be reconstructed.